# BundleConfig - Não encontra arquivos no servidor

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Estou usando `Kendo UI` em um projeto `MVC 4`, fiz as configurações no BudleConfig:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo")
            .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.all.min.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")
        );

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
              .Include("~/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo.common.min.css")
              .Include("~/Content/kendo/2013.2.918/kendo..metronic.min.css")
        );
```

No Html:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
```

Executando no local ele funciona normalmente, mas quando subo pro servidor ele perde as imagens

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://meu.ip/bundles/Metro/loading-image.gif`

Algum motivo especifico pra que isso esteja acontecendo?

Comment: [Esse link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4) demonstra como usar Kendo UI em uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC4, de uma olhada.

Comment: Voce ta colocando a sua aplicação no IIS ?

Comment: Não entendi. Por que as imagens estão sendo carregadas dentro do Bundle?